# Nested forms in symfony empty after form submit

Tags: symfony, nested-forms, symfony-3.4

I have a question related to nested forms in symfony.
I have this form

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'needs-validation'}} ) }}
   ....
   <div id="slot-fields-list" data-prototype="
     {% filter escape %}
        {% include 'slot/form/prototype.html.twig' with {'form': form.slot.vars.prototype} %}
     {% endfilter %}"
     data-widget-tags="{{ '<span></span>'|e }}">
   </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}

  .......................................
  ->add('slot', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type'        => SlotType::class,
            'entry_options'     => ['label' => false],
            'label'             => false,
            'allow_add'         => true,
            'allow_delete'      => true,
            'error_bubbling'    => false
        ])
```

Work fine, I have data in `data-prototype` after render template. When I submit the form and if the form has erreurs this nested form is added after submit button and `data-prototype` is empty. Any ideas ? Thx in advance

Comment: Nested forms are not allowed by the HTML5 specification. so you might experience bizarre behaviors in different browsers.

Comment: Btw at editing works fine on both cases : with and whitout errors on form submit

Comment: show your form builder

Comment: added in message

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for CollectionType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) is actually quite good, but perhaps some particular details need reiteration.

First the documentation tells you, how to render the collection items (your slots probably):

```
<ul class="tags">
    {# iterate over each existing tag and render its only field: name #}
    {% for tag in form.tags %}
        <li>{{ form_row(tag.name) }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is what's missing in your case. Just to avoid confusion, their `<ul class="tags">` is your `<div id="slot-fields-list" ...>`. You have to go through the `form.slot` with

```
{% for slot in form.slot %}
     {{ form_row(slot) }} <!--- or render your sub-form properly -->
{% endfor %}
```

now. Symfony is very reluctant to omit form elements. So when you place a `{{ form_end(form) }}` it will render the rest of the form elements, which have not been rendered before, to your form, before closing the `<form>`. (the same behaviour can be achieved by `{{ form_rest(form) }}`, if you ever need it)

That is the reason, why your subforms will appear after your submit button and completely out of place - because they weren't rendered anywhere before.

However, this does not yet explain the missing `data-prototype`, but perhaps there is a simple explanation as well ...

you possibly already know about the [form themes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html), where you could add your own slot_widget, slot_row, slot_label and have symfony do all that weird include-stuff for you.